# Restructuring TypeScript internal modules to external modules

Tags: typescript, module, webpack, amd, ecmascript-harmony

I have a website that uses a large typescript code base.  All clases as in their own files, and wrapped with an internal module like so:

file BaseClass.ts

```
module my.module {
  export class BaseClass {
  }
}
```

file ChildClass.ts

```
module my.module {
  export ChildClass extends my.module.BaseClass  {
  }
}
```

All file are included globally with script tags, in the appropriate order (using ASP.NET Bundling).

I would like to move to a more modern setup and use webpack.  I would like my module syntax to use whatever the new ECMASCRIPT module standard is.  But there is much code using the existing "module namespaces" so I would like an update path that will support this type of code -

```
let x = new my.module.ChildClass();
```

So I think I need to have something like this -

```
import * as my.module from ???;
```

Or use namespaces?

However, if that is not best practices, I would like to stick with best practices.  The internal modules are currently very helpful for organizing the different application layers and services...

How would I accomplish this since the "module" is across many files?  Really, all I am trying to accomplish is to have a namespace, and get away from global scripts.

Comment: I've created a typescript transformer using the typescript compiler API, so if anyone has this problem feel free to get in touch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer (this is not meant as a comprehensive guide but rather as a conceptual starting point. I hope to demonstrate the feasibility of migration, but ultimately it involves a fair amount of hard work)

I've done this in a large enterprise project. It was not fun, but it worked.

Some tips:

1. Only keep the global namespace object(s) around for as long as you need them.
2. Start at the leaves of your source, converting files which have no dependents into external modules.
3. Although these files will themselves rely on the global namespace object(s) you have been using, this will not be a problem if you work carefully from the outside in.

Say you have a global namespace like `utils` and it is spread across 3 files as follows

```
// utils/geo.ts
namespace utils {
  export function randomLatLng(): LatLng { return implementation(); };
}

// utils/uuid.ts
namespace utils {
  export function uuid(): string { return implementation(); };
}

// utils/http.ts

/// <reference path="./uuid.ts" />
namespace utils {
  export function createHttpClient (autoCacheBust = false) {
    const appendToUrl = autoCacheBust ? `?cacheBust=${uuid()}` : '';
    return {
      get<T>(url, options): Promise<T> {
        return implementation.get(url + appendToUrl, {...options}).then(({data}) => <T>data);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Now imagine you have another globally scoped namespaced file only, this time, we can easily break it out into a proper module because it does not depend on any other members of its *own* namespace. For example I will use a service that queries for weather info at random locations around the globe using the stuff from `utils`.

```
// services/weather-service.ts

/// <reference path="../utils/http.ts" />
/// <reference path="../utils/geo.ts" />
namespace services {
  export const weatherService = {
    const http = utils.http.createHttpClient(true);
    getRandom(): Promise<WeatherData> {
      const latLng = utils.geo.randomLatLng();
      return http
        .get<WeatherData>(`${weatherUrl}/api/v1?lat=${latLng.lat}&lng=${latLng.lng}`);
    }
  }
}
```

No we are going to turn our `services.weatherSercice` global, namespaced constant into a proper external module and it will be fairly easy in this case

```
// services/weather-service.ts

import "../utils/http"; // es2015 side-effecting import to load the global
import "../utils/geo";  // es2015 side-effecting import to load the global
// namespaces loaded above are now available globally and merged into a single utils object

const http = utils.http.createHttpClient(true);

export default { 
    getRandom(): Promise<WeatherData> {
      const latLng = utils.geo.randomLatLng();
      return http
        .get<WeatherData>(`${weatherUrl}/api/v1?lat=${latLng.lat}&lng=${latLng.lng}`);
  } 
}
```

**Common Pitfalls and Workarounds**:

A snag can occur if we need to reference the functionality of this newly modulified code from one of our existing global namespaces

Since we are now using modules for at least some part of our code, we have a module loader or bundler in play (If you writing for NodeJS, i.e an express application you can disregard this as the platform integrates a loader, but you can also use a custom loader). That module loader or bundler could be SystemJS, RequireJS, Webpack, Browserify, or something more esoteric.

The biggest, and most common mistake is to have something like this

```
// app.ts

/// <reference path="./services/weather-service.ts" />
namespace app {
  export async function main() {
    const dataForWeatherWidget = await services.weatherService.getRandom();
  }
}
```

And, as that no longer works, we write this ***broken*** code instead

```
// app.ts

import weatherService from './services/weather-service';

namespace app {
  export async function main() {
    const dataForWeatherWidget = await weatherService.getRandom();
  }
}
```

The above code is broken because, simply by adding an `import... from '...'` statement (the same applies to `import ... = require(...)`) we have turned `app` into a module *accidentally*, before we were ready.

So, we need a workaround. Temporarily, return to the `services` directory and add a new *Module*, here called `weather-service.shim.ts`

```
// services/weather-service.shim.ts

import weatherService from './weather-service.ts';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    services: {
      weatherService: typeof weatherService;
    };
  }
}
window.services.weatherService = weatherService;
```

Then, change `app.ts` to

```
/// <reference path="./services/weather-service.shim.ts" />
namespace app {
  export async function main() {
    const dataForWeatherWidget = await services.weatherService.getRandom();
  }
}
```

Note, this should not be done unless you need to. Try to organize you conversion to modules so as to minimize this.

**Remarks:**

In order to correctly perform this gradual migration it is important to understand precisely what defines what is and what is not a module.

This is determined by language parsers at the source level for each *file*.

When an ECMAScript file is parsed, there are two possible *goal symbols*, *Script* and *Module*.

https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/notational-conventions.html#sec-syntactic-grammar

> #### 5.1.4 The Syntactic Grammar
>
> The *syntactic grammar* for ECMAScript is given in clauses [13](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-ecmascript-language-expressions) through [16](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules). This grammar has ECMAScript tokens defined by the lexical grammar as its terminal symbols ([5.1.2](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/notational-conventions.html#sec-lexical-and-regexp-grammars)). It defines a set of productions, starting from two alternative [goal symbols](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/notational-conventions.html#sec-context-free-grammars) [Script](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-Script) and [Module](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-Module), that describe how sequences of tokens form syntactically correct independent components of ECMAScript programs.
>
> When a stream of code points is to be parsed as an ECMAScript [Script](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-Script) or [Module](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-Module), it is first converted to a stream of input elements by repeated application of the lexical grammar; this stream of input elements is then parsed by a single application of the syntactic grammar. The input stream is syntactically in error if the tokens in the stream of input elements cannot be parsed as a single instance of the goal nonterminal ([Script](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-Script) or [Module](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#prod-Module)), with no tokens left over.

Hand-wavingly, a *Script* is a global. Code written using TypeScript's *internal modules*, always falls into this category.

A source file is a *Module* when and only when it contains one or more top level `import` or `export` statements*. TypeScript used to refer to such sources as *external modules* but they are now known simply as *modules* in order to match the ECMAScript specification's terminology.

Here are some source examples of scripts and modules. Note that how they are differentiated is subtle yet well-defined.

**square.ts** --> *Script*

```
// This is a Script
// `square` is attached to the global object.

function square(n: number) {
  return n ** 2;
}
```

**now.ts** --> *Script*

```
// This is also a Script
// `now` is attached to the global object.
// `moment` is not imported but rather assumed to be available, attached to the global.

var now = moment();
```

**square.ts** --> *Module*

```
// This is a Module. It has an `export` that exports a named function, square.
// The global is not polluted and `square` must be imported for use in other modules.

export function square(n: number) {
  return n ** 2;
}
```

**bootstrap.ts** --> *Module*

```
// This is also a Module it has a top level `import` of moment. It exports nothing.
import moment from 'moment';

console.info('App started running at: ' + moment());
```

**bootstrap.ts** --> *Script*

```
// This is a Script (global) it has no top level `import` or `export`.
// moment refers to a global variable

console.info('App started running at: ' + moment());
```

Comment: @user210757 Thank you! I just added a new section, based on a common pitfall, offering a workaround, check it out as you will likely run into it.

Comment: I have /services/myservice.ts: `namespace services { export class myservice { .. } }`, then in /some/dir/myclass.ts:  `import "../../services/myservice"; class myClass { constructor() { let s = new services.myservice(); }}`. The import resolves but the `services.myservice()` line gives me a design time error - _cannot find name services_

Comment: @user210757 I tried to reproduce and could not. If the file `/servecies/myservice.ts` has a top level import or export it will not work. Otherwise, your tsconfig may be the issue. Make sure you have spelled everything correctly and make sure everything is up to date.

Comment: I do use vendor libs in "myservice", so I have import statements at the top; ex: `import * as thirdParty from 'third-party';`

Comment: That is why it does not work. A top level `import` or `export` literally defines the source file to be a module. If the third party  library is being used by a global such as `services.myservice`, it should be usable as a global. Don't import it. The compiler will pick it up automatically (if not there are other ways to refer to it).

Comment: @user210757 I added a **Remarks** section to provide context and technical details, hopefully explaining and clarifying source type distinctions. It has citations and examples, and I hope it helps :). Let me know if something is unclear, but also keep in mind the this is a complex topic.

Comment: This part sounds like exactly what I'm looking for in my case:
`import "../utils/http.ts"; // es2015 side-effecting import to load the global`
But I can't get the behaviour described in the comment. If I use the `.ts` extension, there's a runtime error because the runtime tries to parse the Typescript as Javascript. If I remove the file extension in the import, the global variables from the imported script are not available. Is there some magic that makes an `import`ed script set global variables?

Comment: @TimS Sorry, I had syntax errors. Specifically, you can use the `.ts` file extension in the reference path directive but not in an import statement. You can use a `.js` extension or no extension at all. If it doesn't work then it probably has something to do with your module bundler. I've done this using RequireJS and SystemJS but Webpack  may require some additional setup